# convert from 'const QVector<QVector<qreal>>' to 'QVector<QVector<qreal>>'

Tags: c++, casting, const-cast, qvector, qdatastream

How can I solve the following, ie, converting `const QVector<QVector<qreal>>` to `QVector<QVector<qreal>>`?

I tried a few steps but didn't help:

```
QVector<QVector<qreal>> points = const_cast<QVector<QVector<qreal>>>(abc.points);
```

abc.points is a struct element of type `QVector<QVector<qreal>>`, which I'm trying to extract from a `QDataStream`:

```
QDataStream& operator >> (QDataStream& in, const CustomPointCloud& abc)
{
    quint32 pointsCount = quint32(abc.pointsCount);
    QVector<QVector<qreal>> points =
        const_cast<QVector<QVector<qreal>>>(abc.points);
    in >> pointsCount >> points;
    return in;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done by
`QVector<QVector<qreal>> points(abc.points);`

Please suggest if there are other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` takes by `const`, because it does not modify the parameter, whereas the whole point of `>>` is to modify the parameter.

You should change your function definition. You are reading data from the stream into a local object which ceases to exist at the end of the function.

```
QDataStream& operator >> (QDataStream& in, CustomPointCloud& abc)
{
    quint32 pointsCount;
    in >> pointsCount;
    in >> abc.points;
    return in;
}
```

I would also suggest that you don't need the count of points to extract the stream, the underlying [`QDataStream& >> (QDataStream&, QVector<T>&)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#operator-gt-gt) template deals with that. The pair of operators would then be

```
QDataStream& operator >> (QDataStream& in, CustomPointCloud& abc)
{
    return in >> abc.points;
}

QDataStream& operator << (QDataStream& out, const CustomPointCloud& abc)
{
    return out << abc.points;
}
```

Comment: Yes I found that const was the issue.